# Согласование сказуемого с подлежащим

Tags: стилистика, грамотная-речь

При подлежащем, выраженном сочетанием собирательного существительного ( ряд, большинство, меньшинство, часть и т.п.) и существительного в форме родительного падежа множественного числа, сказуемое обычно ставится в форме множественного числа, если речь идёт о предметах одушевлённых или **если подчёркивается активность действия**. 
Не могли бы вы объяснить последний пункт на примере? Спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

Большинство горожан собира**ют**ся участвовать в выборах губернатора.

(без подчёркивания активности было бы согласование по числу с "большинством" и по стилю это было бы нейтральной ссылкой на данные опроса)

Answer (score 1):

> ...**или** если подчёркивается активность действия. Не могли бы вы
>   объяснить последний пункт на примере?

***Множество рук*** стуч**ат** во все окна с улицы... (Лесков).

Comment: Я правильно понял: активность действия это значит что действие не есть законченное? Много сирен гудят на улице. (Сейчас)